# Ansible - how to keep double quotes inside single quotes?

Tags: ansible

Ideally i have this one `"{{result |json_query('"{{ val }}"[*]')}}"` in order words, if i hard code value. `"{{result |json_query('one[*]')}}"`

outer double quotes... and single quotes for insde json_query and val is a variable so i need to include the double quotes added like this `"{{ val }}"`  .

Here is what i am trying. but no luck.

```
with_items: "{{result |json_query(''"'{{ val }}'"'[*]')}}"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it directly. For your use case define a variable:

```
with_items: "{{ result | json_query(myquery) }}"
vars:
  myquery: "{{ val }}"
```

<sub>Sorry for the example only, but I have no willpower to figure out from what you wrote in the question what is your intended query. There's another example in the chapter on [JSON query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter).</sub>

Comment: still i would need to handle this one. `{{ val }} [*]`

Comment: the link you shared helped.

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but this worked for me ``"{{ result | json_query( '`{{ val }}`[*]' ) }}"``.  Notice the back quotes in the query string.